# Updates and Inserts

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, updates, apache-nifi

We are receiving Hourly JSON data into HDFS. The size of the data would be approx 5-6 GB per hour.

- when matched record found on the final table then Update (or) Delete
- if the record not matched in the final dataset then insert the record.

We have tried the Hive merge option for the USE case . this is taking more than an hour to process the merge operation in Hive . Is there any other alternative approach to resolve the use case.So basically every day we are adding 150GB of data into hive , Every other day We have to scan 150Gb of data to find whether we need to do update/insert

What is best way to do Upserts(Updates and Inserts in Hadoop) for large dataset. Hive or HBase or Nifi . What is flow.

Comment: Use NiFi to convert the JSON into Avro/Parquet/ORC, then write to Hive. There is no benefit of storing data in plaintext JSON

Comment: I have missed it , We are converting the data to ORC and merging in Hive . But it is taking long time to merge when the final data becomes huge .

Comment: Are you creating hourly table partitions as well? Can you show your Nifi flow?

Comment: generally, record updates for hive isn't a good pattern, HBase may be a better fit for your use case

Answer (score 1):

We are using uber's [Hoodie](https://uber.github.io/hudi/) library for a similar use case. It uses spark library with partition and bloom filter index for faster merging. It supports Hive and Presto.

[DeltaStreamer Tool](https://github.com/uber/hudi/blob/master/docs/incremental_processing.md#deltastreamer-tool) can be used for quick setup and initial testing